# MySQL is not using index on multiple joins

Tags: mysql, performance

I have a simple query which is working as expected: it joins a t2 by the index (type = index in the `explain` query):

```sql
select t1.id 
from table1 t1
left join table2 t2 on t1.vendor_id = t2.vendor_id
```

But when I add one more join, it's not using the index (type = ALL in the `explain` query):

```sql
select t1.id 
from table1 t1
left join table2 t2 on t1.vendor_id = t2.vendor_id
left join table3 t3 on t2.vendor_t2_id = t3.vendor_t2_id
```

How can I fix this, so all tables are joining by an index?

Comment: Provide DDLs of all 3 tables. And sync fieldnames - they differs in queries.

Comment: As @Akina suggests - please provide the tables' DDL - in the form of **fomatted text** - use the command `SHOW CREATE TABLE foo\G` for this - it gives the best output which can then be copied and pasted as required. Some sample data would also be good - in the form of a fiddle even better with your desired result. p.s. welcome to the forum! :-)

Comment: Also provide the `EXPLAIN`.